# Creating a new array from 2 existing ones in assembly x86

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, x86-16

So, I have the following the arrays (bytes).

s1 db 1362375

s2 db 6381259

Starting from them, I have to create another array which would contain the maximum on each position, leading to an array looking like this

d db 6382379

I'm trying to do it using instructions on strings (such as SCASB, MOVSB, etc).

The code below is based on the following idea: the data of S1 is moved to D, then it's compared to the data in S2. If it's the case, a change would be made.

```
ASSUME cs:text_,ds:data_

data_ SEGMENT

s1 db '1362375'
l equ $-s1
s2 db '6381259' 
d db l dup (?)

data_ ENDS

text_ SEGMENT
start:
    mov ax, data_
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov si, offset s1  ;data of s1 is moved to si
    mov di, offset d   ;data of d is moved to di
    mov cx, l          ;length is stored in cx
    cld                ;setting the direction
    rep movsb    
    mov di, 0      ;moving data from si to di (d takes the value of s1)
    mov cx, 2*l
    Repeta:
        lodsb
        cmp al,[di]   
        jng do_not_write 
        mov [di],al     ;if s2 is greater than s1, it goes to the next instruction 
        do_not_write: 
            inc di
        dec cx
    loop Repeta
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
text_ ENDS
end start
```

Thing is, it moves my first array and then that's is, it doesn't do what I planned it to do. Since I'm pretty much a beginner in assembly language, any help would be much appreciated (and yes, I'm aware it could've been done in another way as well, I prefered this option since it seemed easier). Also, sorry if the comments don't seem explainatory, English is not my native language, therefore I've tried my best to explain what I did using each instruction.

Later edit: the code works now, I just need to store the result in d (which doesn't seem to work with movsb)

Comment: `push si            ;emptying si`  What? You can't "empty" register, register just **exists** in the CPU (has some value all the time). `push si` will store current `si` value into the stack memory, so you can restore it back with for example `pop si` later, if you want (or just discard it by restoring `sp`: `add sp,2` at appropriate place instead of `pop`, but then you don't need to `push` it at all). And after the `rep movsb`, due to way how you defined `s1` and `s2`, the `si` already is equal to `offset s2` accidentally, so the next `mov si, offset s2` will overwrite it with same value.

Comment: @Ped7g thank you for the clarification regarding the push instruction, I'll change it right away

Comment: You may want to recheck more instructions, what exactly they do, like `scasb` too. You can use some simplified instruction reference guide like http://x86.renejeschke.de/ as the Intel documentation is a bit too large for quick search (unless you know it well), but in case of some typo or if you need more info, the Intel docs are ultimate resource. `lodsb` `dec si` `scasb` is sort of overcomplicating it, `lodsb` `cmp al,[di]` is enough. Also reset the `di` ahead of that, as `di` is modified by `rep movsb` already. Use debugger to verify all registers contain values like you expect, single step.

Comment: Then you can use `stosb` to store `al` to `es:[di]` if it is greater, or just `inc di` to skip (keep `s1` value there). I.e. full loop body: `lodsb ; al = s2[i++]` `cmp al,[di] ; compare against d[j]` `jle do_not_write` `mov [di],al ; overwrite d[j] with s2[i] value` `do_not_write: inc di ; ++j` `... loop l times...` in the end even `stosb` is just disturbing things. The simpler `mov/inc` instructions are generally faster than "string" `lods/stos/scas/cmps/...`, only `rep XXX` when fixed operation over `cx` elements is needed are usually on equal with simple code.

Comment: Biggest benefit of "string" instructions on modern x86 CPU is when coding for size, otherwise modern x86 is optimized for ordinary `mov/inc/add/dec/jnz/...` code produced by compilers, the `movs/stos/lods/scas/...` extended instructions are emulated by the internal microcode of modern x86 CPU, as they are not expected to happen in application code at all, compilers generally don't use them, only hand written assembly.

Comment: It works now. Thanks a lot @Ped7g!!!